# A reusable card component

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, angular-2+

I tried to create a reusable component which would allow the user to create cards which can have a header, cover image, avatar section (image, title and sub title), a description, a table, a list and a few buttons (add, delete, edit, like, share). All of these are optional and the user can omit whatever is not needed for a card. Here is the Github link [nevescard component github repo](https://github.com/SagarMajumdar/nevescard). The end result will looks like this

[image: screenshot of some ways in which the card component can be used]

The component is called neves-card

[image: neves-card component]

in app.component.ts the data needed for the card(s) is defined as

```
 x = [ 
    {
      indx: '58',
         features : ['title-main', 'card-cover', 'avatar', 'main-desc', 'tbl', 'list', 'btn-add', 'btn-del', 'btn-share', 'btn-like', 'btn-edit']
       , nevesCardTitleMain: 'consequatur saepe rerum est sint'
       ,nevesCardCover : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480911620066-b6ccd99c48f3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1342&q=80'
       ,nevesCardAvatarImg :'https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/182/images/circle/Chimpanzees_Circle_image_%28c%29_Howard_W._Buffett_WWF_US.jpg?1345516061'
       ,nevesCardAvatarTitle : 'ljsdkin jshdfj'
       ,nevesCardAvatarDesc : 'kjfhjfg jfgjshgfshgfjhgj | jhsgfhjsgf | kdha skjjkad '
       ,nevesCardMainDesc :'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus doloribus tempora, atque dolore quasi aperiam. Tempora nam aut a dolores, praesentium corporis dolorem, accusantium velit minima laudantium excepturi voluptate eum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ducimus qui esse ab delectus, quo quod consectetur, repudiandae deserunt sequi praesentium tempora adipisci ea quidem a numquam maiores. Consectetur, pariatur?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A deleniti odio odit et accusamus perspiciatis quo minima asperiores, consequatur saepe rerum est sint ipsum, itaque dicta. Laudantium libero molestiae aperiam.'
       , tbldata : [
         {head1: 'data1', head2: 'data2' },
         {head1: 'data6', head2: 'data299' },
         {head1: 'data313', head2: 'data12'}]    
       , listData: {
         list_title: 'list one',
         list_content: [ 'abc', 'dsadasd', 'gdgeewrw', 'dsdda', 'dadsssd','gdgeewrw asdada dasd','gdgeewrw asdada dasd','gdgeewrw asdada dasd','gdgeewrw asdada dasd','gdgeewrw asdada dasd' ]
       }
  }

  ,
  { 
    indx: '21',
         features : ['card-cover', 'avatar', 'list', 'btn-add', 'btn-like', 'btn-edit', 'btn-share']
    , nevesCardTitleMain: ''
    ,   nevesCardCover : 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/894443/pexels-photo-894443.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260'
    ,   nevesCardAvatarImg : 'https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/182/images/circle/Chimpanzees_Circle_image_%28c%29_Howard_W._Buffett_WWF_US.jpg?1345516061'
    ,   nevesCardAvatarTitle : 'Fhijkj jhhjgada '
    ,   nevesCardAvatarDesc : 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum'
    ,   nevesCardMainDesc : ''
    ,    tbldata : [{}]
      , listData: {
         list_title: 'list two',
         list_content: [ 'abc', 'dsadasd','gdgeewrw asdada dasd','gdgeewrw asdada dasd' ]
       }
  },
  {
    indx: '3',
    features : ['title-main', 'card-cover', 'main-desc', 'tbl','btn-add', 'tn-del', 'btn-like', 'btn-edit']
    ,nevesCardTitleMain: 'consequatur saepe rerum est sint'
   ,    nevesCardCover : 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/b8/f8/c6/b8f8c61ca7d9050b3045eb118d2cdedc.jpg'
   ,    nevesCardAvatarImg : ''
    ,   nevesCardAvatarTitle : ''
    ,   nevesCardAvatarDesc : ''
    ,   nevesCardMainDesc :'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus doloribus tempora, atque dolore quasi aperiam. Tempora nam aut a dolores, praesentium corporis dolorem, accusantium velit minima laudantium excepturi voluptate eum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ducimus qui esse ab delectus, quo quod consectetur, repudiandae deserunt sequi praesentium tempora adipisci ea quidem a numquam maiores. Consectetur, pariatur?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A deleniti odio odit et accusamus perspiciatis quo minima asperiores, consequatur saepe rerum est sint ipsum, itaque dicta. Laudantium libero molestiae aperiam.'
    ,    tbldata : [{head1: 'data1', head2: 'data2',head12: 'data1', head23: 'data2',head41: 'data1', head62: 'data2',head18: 'data1', head29: 'data2',head01: 'data1', head02: 'data2',head09: 'data1', head03: 'data2',head04: 'data1', head05: 'data2',head06: 'data1', head011: 'data2',head012: 'data1', head013: 'data2'}]
    , listData: {
         list_title: '',
         list_content: []
       }
  },
  {
    indx: '42',
    features : ['title-main', 'card-cover', 'main-desc','btn-add', 'btn-del', 'btn-like', 'btn-edit','btn-share']
    ,nevesCardTitleMain: 'consequatur saepe rerum est sint'
   ,    nevesCardCover : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576895225171-ce4059ba7d3c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60'
   ,   nevesCardAvatarImg :''
    ,   nevesCardAvatarTitle : ''
    ,   nevesCardAvatarDesc : ''
    ,   nevesCardMainDesc :"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus doloribus tempora, atque dolore quasi aperiam. Tempora nam aut a dolores, praesentium corporis dolorem, accusantium velit minima laudantium excepturi voluptate eum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ducimus qui esse ab delectus, quo quod consectetur, repudiandae deserunt sequi praesentium tempora adipisci ea quidem a numquam maiores. Consectetur, pariatur?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A deleniti odio odit et accusamus perspiciatis quo minima asperiores, consequatur saepe rerum est sint ipsum, itaque dicta. Laudantium libero molestiae aperiam."
    ,    tbldata : [{}]
    , listData: {
         list_title: '',
         list_content: []
       }
  },
  {
    indx: '6',
    features : ['title-main']
    ,nevesCardTitleMain: 'consequatur saepe rerum est sint consequatur saepe rerum'
    ,    nevesCardCover : ''
    ,   nevesCardAvatarImg :''
     ,   nevesCardAvatarTitle : '' 
     ,   nevesCardAvatarDesc : ''
     ,   nevesCardMainDesc : ''
     ,    tbldata : [{}]
     , listData: {
          list_title: '',
          list_content: []
        }
  },
  {
    indx: '12',
    features : ['card-cover']
    ,nevesCardTitleMain: ''
    ,    nevesCardCover : 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8c/cd/97/8ccd97ebaab901742670abbe2f353c53.jpg'
    ,   nevesCardAvatarImg :''
     ,   nevesCardAvatarTitle : '' 
     ,   nevesCardAvatarDesc : ''
     ,   nevesCardMainDesc :''
     ,    tbldata : [{}]
     , listData: {
          list_title: '',
          list_content: []
        }
  } 
  ];
```

calling the card component

```
<app-neves-card  *ngFor="let v of x"
       [nevesIndx] = "v.indx"
       [nevesFeatures]="v.features"
       [nevesAction]="v.nevesAction"
       [nevesCardTitleMain] = "v.nevesCardTitleMain"
       [nevesCardCover] = "v.nevesCardCover"
       [nevesCardAvatarImg] ="v.nevesCardAvatarImg"
       [nevesCardAvatarTitle] = "v.nevesCardAvatarTitle" 
       [nevesCardAvatarDesc] = "v.nevesCardAvatarDesc"
       [nevesCardMainDesc] ="v.nevesCardMainDesc"
       [tblData]="v.tbldata"
       [listData] = "v.listData"
       (outAdd)="fnAdd($event)"
       (outDel)="fnDel($event)"
       (outEdit)="fnEdit($event)"
       (outLike)="fnLike($event)"
       (outShare)="fnShare($event)"
></app-neves-card>
```

neves-card.component.html

```
<div class="neves-card-container-main">
<div class="neves-card-container" >
    <div class="neves-card-title-main" appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'title-main'" ><h2>{{nevesCardTitleMain}}</h2></div>
    <div class="neves-card-cover" appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'card-cover'">
        <img [src]="nevesCardCover" > 
    </div>
    <div class="neves-card-avatar-wrapper" appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'avatar'">
           <div class="neves-card-avatar-img"><img [src]="nevesCardAvatarImg"></div>
           <div class="neves-card-avatar-details">
                <div class="neves-card-avatar-title"><h4>{{nevesCardAvatarTitle}}</h4></div>
                <div class="neves-card-avatar-desc"><p>{{nevesCardAvatarDesc}}</p></div>
           </div>
    </div>
    <div class="neves-card-main-desc"  appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'main-desc'">       
        <p>{{nevesCardMainDesc}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="neves-card-tbl" appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'tbl'">
         <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let head of headers">{{head}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr   *ngFor="let row of tblData">
                        <td  *ngFor="let head of headers">
                            {{ row[head] }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                </tfoot>
        </table>     
    </div>

    <div class="neves-card-list" appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'list'">
       <p>{{listData.list_title}}</p>
       <ol>
            <li *ngFor="let dt of listData.list_content">
                {{dt}}
            </li>
       </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="neves-card-buttons">
        <button type="button"  (click)='nevesAdd(nevesIndx)' appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'btn-add'">+</button>
        <button type="button"   (click)='nevesDel(nevesIndx)' appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'btn-del'">-</button>
        <button type="button"  (click)='nevesEdit(nevesIndx)' appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'btn-edit'"><img src="assets/images/edit.png"></button>
        <button type="button"   (click)='nevesLike(nevesIndx)' appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'btn-like'"><img src="assets/images/heart.png"></button>
        <button type="button"  (click)='nevesShare(nevesIndx)' appSectionHider [isFeatureRequested]="nevesFeatures" [currElem]="'btn-share'"><img src="assets/images/share.png"></button>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

neves-card.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-neves-card',
  templateUrl: './neves-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./neves-card.component.css']
})
export class NevesCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() nevesCardTitleMain: string;
  @Input() nevesCardCover: string;
  @Input() nevesCardAvatarImg: string;
  @Input() nevesCardAvatarTitle: string;
  @Input() nevesCardAvatarDesc: string;
  @Input() nevesCardMainDesc: string;
  @Input() tblData;
  @Input() nevesAction: string[];
  @Input() nevesFeatures: string[];
  @Input()  listData: string[];
  @Input() nevesIndx: string;

  headers: string[] = [];

  @Output() outAdd = new EventEmitter<{nevesindx:string}>();
  @Output() outDel = new EventEmitter<{nevesindx:string}>();
  @Output() outEdit = new EventEmitter<{nevesindx:string}>();
  @Output() outLike = new EventEmitter<{nevesindx:string}>();
  @Output() outShare = new EventEmitter<{nevesindx:string}>();


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.headers = Object.keys(this.tblData[0]);
  }


  nevesAdd = (indx: string) => { this.outAdd.emit({nevesindx:indx});}
  nevesDel = (indx: string) => { this.outDel.emit({nevesindx:indx}); }
  nevesEdit = (indx: string) => { this.outEdit.emit({nevesindx:indx});}
  nevesLike = (indx: string) => { this.outLike.emit({nevesindx:indx});}
  nevesShare = (indx: string) => { this.outShare.emit({nevesindx:indx});}


}
```

neves-card.component.css

```
*{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.neves-card-title-main , 
.neves-card-avatar-wrapper,
.neves-card-main-desc,
.neves-card-buttons,
.neves-card-tbl,
.neves-card-list {
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.neves-card-cover img{
    width:100%;
}
.neves-card-container-main 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.neves-card-container {
    max-width:350px;
    border: 1px solid gainsboro;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin:5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px gainsboro;

}
.neves-card-avatar-wrapper {
    margin-top:10px;
    width:100%;
}
.neves-card-avatar-img{
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.neves-card-avatar-img img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.neves-card-avatar-details {
    margin-left:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:65%;

}
.neves-card-avatar-details h4 {
    margin:0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: small;
}
.neves-card-avatar-details p {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: smaller;

}
.neves-card-main-desc p {
    font-size: small;
}
.neves-card-main-desc
{

    height: 125px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.neves-card-buttons {

    text-align: right;
}
.neves-card-buttons button {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:gray;
}

.neves-card-tbl {
    _border-radius: 3px;
    _overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.neves-card-tbl table {
    min-width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead th {
    text-align: left;
    background-color:#616161;
    color:white;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: small;
    padding: 5px;
}
tbody td {
    font-size: small;
    border-left:1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid #bbbaba;
    padding:4px;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: gainsboro;
} 
.neves-card-list {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-size: smaller;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.neves-card-list p 
{
    background-color: #616161;
    color:white;
    padding:4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.neves-card-list ol li {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding:3px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

section-hider.directive.ts

```
import { Directive ,ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSectionHider]'
})
export class SectionHiderDirective implements OnInit{
  @Input() isFeatureRequested :string[];
  @Input() currElem:string;

  constructor(private elref : ElementRef, private renderer : Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.isFeatureRequested !== undefined && 
      this.isFeatureRequested.length>0 &&
      this.isFeatureRequested.indexOf(this.currElem) === -1 ) {

          this.renderer.setStyle(this.elref.nativeElement, 'display' , 'none');
      }
    if(this.isFeatureRequested === undefined || 
      this.isFeatureRequested.length === 0) {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.elref.nativeElement, 'display' , 'none');
      } 
  }

}
```

Can anyone give feedback on:

1. how the code is written and what changes can be done to improve it?
2. how is the UI and is it effective?
3. what other featured can be added to the component?
4. any other feedback

Any feedback weather positive or negative will be appreciated.

Comment: Since your component is pretty complex (and a bit unreadable) I would suggest composing your main card from a number of child components. For example the table and the badge could be their own component.